# How do I run bash command with "while" loop in desktop entry without having to create a ".sh" file?

Tags: bash, .desktop

If I copy and paste the following command on a terminal it works as expected:

```
    uxterm -e "bash -c 'while :
do
    xdotool getmouselocation;   sleep 0.3
done'"
```

The following desktop entry works as expected as well:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=getLocation_v1      
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside
Exec=uxterm -e "bash -c 'xdotool getmouselocation;sleep 0.3;$SHELL'"
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

But for some reason the following desktop entry does not work:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=getLocation
Comment=Test the terminal running a command inside
Exec=uxterm -e "bash -c 'while :
do
    xdotool getmouselocation;   sleep 0.3
done'"
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this desktop entry so that it works without having to create an adittional ".sh" file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
uxterm -e "bash -c 'while : ; do xdotool getmouselocation ;   sleep 0.3 ; done'"
```

The secret is to replace the line breaks by the `;` command separator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your suggestion worked!

Comment: Lemme guess, .desktop file grammar is too simple to store newlines.